# Sn the sum of the first n odd numbers

Tags: arithmetic

i need help to solve a question that say :

**Sn** the sum of the first **n** odd numbers

1 - Formalize this sum: (Give mathematical expression)?

2 - Calculate this sum?

how to solve that ? :/

Comment: Compute the first few case.  $1=1$, $1+3 = 4$, $1+3+5=9$.  Keep going until you can guess the pattern.

Comment: Do you know the formula for $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i$?

Comment: @Adel It could be useful see your full work for the solution here in the OP. Bye

Comment: @gimusi yep i know this formula, but how to calculate the odd numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

- consider the sum of the first $2n$ numbers, that is

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n} k=1+2+3+\ldots+(2n-1)+2n$$

- subtract the sum of the first $n$ even numbers picking out a factor 2

$$2+4+6+\ldots+(2n-2)+2n=2\sum_{k=1}^{n} k$$

Comment: i cant understand, can u explain !

Comment: The idea is to sum all the even and odd numbers since we know the formula, that is for example to obtain the sum of the first 3 odd numbers, that is up to 5 we calculate: $$1+3+5=(1+2+3+4+5+6)-(2+4+6)=(1+2+3+4+5+6)-2(1+2+3)$$ Can you see the method now?

Comment: yes, now its very clear thank u :)

Comment: @Adel Well done. You are welcome! If you want to show your final expression here above in the OP, I can get a look to it. Bye

Answer (score 1):

There is a very neat pictorial proof of the solution dated as far back as the Pythagorean schools who considered every number to have a shape apparently.

Try drawing the odd numbers as "L" shapes of dots,

i.e. \begin{array}{cc}
\blacksquare \\
\\
 \end{array} \begin{array}{cc}
\blacksquare \\
\blacksquare &  \blacksquare\\
 \end{array}
\begin{array}{cc}
\blacksquare \\
\blacksquare \\
\blacksquare & \blacksquare &  \blacksquare\\
 \end{array}for 1, 3, and 5 and so on, then see what happens when you put them together.

p.s. apologies for my LaTeX, if someone can make it look prettier by all means go ahead and edit. Thanks

Comment: +1: good answer. Suggestion about the $\LaTeX$: \color seems to work with MathJax {\color{blue}\blacksquare} etc. gives me: $\color{blue}\blacksquare$, $\color{red}\blacksquare$, $\color{green}\blacksquare$, $\ldots$

Answer (score 1):

Here's the [$A=B$](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html) solution: $S_1 = 1 = 1 = 1^2$, $S_2 = 1 + 3 = 4 = 2^2$, $S_3 = 1 + 3 + 5 = 9 = 3^2$. Taking [differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Relationship_to_difference_equations_narrowly_defined), we see that the formula must be a quadratic in $n$; three values of a quadratic determine the quadratic: we must have $S_n = n^2$ for all $n$.